# how to prevent products to jump lines in list view (css)

Tags: css, products

I have problem with my products on homepage. I want to show my products in 2 row with 4 products in one row but in second row I have 2 products and other 2 products go in next row.

This is css that I use to customize my products

```
.products-grid li.item {
float: left;
width: 170px;
padding: 0px 10px 4px;
}
```

Here is screenshot of my page:

[image: Screenshot]

I don't have an idea how to fix that :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the column count is correct, meaning you have 4 items per row then it's probably caused by one item being higher than the others. You probably have 2 solutions.

1. Give the li.item a fixed height
2. Make the .products-grid floating with a `clear: both;` to ensure each row is put under the last one